# Вывод форматированного текста (цифры) в html

Tags: html

Подскажите как форматировать текст (цифры) в тегэ label? Например есть такой блок html

```
<label for="InputHeight" class="col-sm-6 control-label" id="labelArea"</label>
```

в javascript вычисляется цифровое выражение и выводится в эту метку. Вот пример вывода:

```
Ширина * Высота =72250
```

Как мне цифру 72250 превратить в 72,250 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для форматирования можно воспользоваться функцией [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
document.write(72250..toLocaleString('en'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно через регулярное выражение:

```js
var number = "72250";

console.log(number.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")); // с точкой
console.log(number.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")); // с запятой
console.log(number.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1 ")); // с пробелом
```

Answer (score 0):

После каждого символа, за которым до конца строки следует кратное трём (и при этом ненулевое) количество цифр, добавляем пробел:

```js
console.log(("" + 123456789).replace(/.(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$& "))
```

Comment: Скопировал из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/579058/178988, раз уж тот вопрос закрыли как дубликат этого.