# Разделение целых тысяч от сотен и единиц

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<script>
    function mp()
    { 
      document.getElementById('mpol').value =  (parseFloat(document.getElementById('kolrap').value) * parseFloat(document.getElementById('height').value)|| 0).toFixed(0) ;
    }
    document.getElementById('kolrap').addEventListener('input',mp);
    document.getElementById('height').addEventListener('input',mp);
</script>
```

При выводе ответа будет например 345354
Нужно чтобы выводило 345 354
Пробел после "тысяч" так сказать

Comment: как вариант заюзать библиотечку http://numeraljs.com/ или любую другую на эту тему, но если задача требует делать это в одном месте то лучше, я думаю, написать в ручную.

Comment: зачем библиотеку, regex отлично делит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После каждого символа, за которым до конца строки следует кратное трём (и при этом ненулевое) количество цифр, добавляем пробел:

```
("" + 123456789).replace(/.(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$& ")
```

Comment: А зачем подстановку $ использовать? Можно и просто " ".

Comment: @nick_n_a, нельзя. Приведи пример замены, дам контрпример.

Comment: @nick_n_a, потому что регулярка захватывает 1 символ. И данное в ответе решение не работает для чисел со знаками после запятой.

Comment: не совсем понятен код.

Comment: а где его писать в моем коде?

Comment: @nick_n_a, потому что получится `12 45 789` - где 3 и 6?

Comment: @BigDaddy, что именно непонятно?

Comment: Не досмотрел точку. Я так использую `("" + 123456789).replace(/(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, " ")`.

Comment: @nick_n_a, так `" 123 456 789"` - первый пробел лишний :)

Comment: @nick_n_a, вот так можно: `("" + 123456789).replace(/(?!^)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, " ")`, но не вижу, чем бы это было лучше.

Comment: если не сложно, то я бы хотел узнать, что значит каждый элемент этого кода.

Comment: Вот у меня значение выводится в document.getElementById('mpol').value, как ему "прикрепить данный код"?

Comment: @BigDaddy, ответ дополнен.

Comment: Помогло!Благодарю всех!

Comment: @BigDaddy, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку.