# Jquery-ui - как добавить пробелы в цене у калькулятора?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Как добавить пробелы в input при вводе суммы или перемещении ползунка?
Например, 300000 = 300 000.

```js
$('.calculator').each(function() {
  let
    sum = 3000000,
    time = 15,
    percent = $(this).data('percent');

  const recount = () => {
    const revenue = Math.floor(sum * ((time * 30) * percent / 365 / 100)).toLocaleString();
    $('.revenue span', this).html(revenue + ' &#8381;');
  };

  $(this).on('change keyup', '.amount', e => {
    sum = +$(e.target).val();
    $('.slider-range-min', this).slider('value', sum);
    recount();
  });
  $(this).on('change keyup', '.amount2', e => {
    time = +$(e.target).val();
    $('.slider-range-min2', this).slider('value', time);
    recount();
  });

  $('input[type="text"]', this).on('change', function() {
    const
      $this = $(this),
      data = $this.data();

    $this.val(Math.min(data.max, Math.max(data.min, $this.val())));
  });

  $('.slider-range-min', this).slider({
    range: 'min',
    step: 50000,
    value: 3000000,
    min: $('.amount', this).data('min'),
    max: $('.amount', this).data('max'),
    slide: (event, ui) => {
      $('.amount', this).val(ui.value).trigger('change');
    }
  });
  $('.amount', this).val($('.slider-range-min', this).slider('value').toLocaleString());

  $('.slider-range-min2', this).slider({
    range: 'min',
    value: 15,
    min: $('.amount2', this).data('min'),
    max: $('.amount2', this).data('max'),
    slide: (event, ui) => {
      $('.amount2', this).val(ui.value).trigger('change');
    }
  });
  $('.amount2', this).val($('.slider-range-min2', this).slider('value'));

  recount();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  background-color: #2c3844;
  color: #34a3db;
}

span {
  color: #91e8fc;
}

input+span {
  color: red;
}

.ui-widget-content {
  background: #6b6b6b;
  border-color: #6b6b6b;
}

.ui-slider-handle {
  background: #c1c2c4;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
}

.ui-slider-range {
  background: #34a3db;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<div class="calculator" data-percent="2">
  <p>
    <label>
      Сумма (руб.):
      <input type="text" class="amount" data-max="60000000" data-min="50000">
    </label>
  </p>
  <div class="slider-range-min"></div>
  <p>
    <label>
      Срок (мес.):
      <input type="text" class="amount2" data-max="30" data-min="1">
    </label>
  </p>
  <div class="slider-range-min2"></div>
  <p class="revenue">Стоимость составит: <strong><span></span></strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/579058/178988

Comment: Добавил `$this.val(("" + $this.val()).replace(/.(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, "$& "));` пробелы в input добавляются. Но теперь в расчете пишет "не число". Можете объяснить почему так происходит? [Посмотреть вживую](http://jsfiddle.net/y4w7a3og/1/)

Comment: Потому что строка с пробелами внутри к числу нормально не приводится.